# How much time must pass before making a second beracha on the same food?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, time

If you made a beracha on a food or drink item and you took a sampling of it, how much time must pass until the next sampling for you to be required to make an additional beracha?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7187

Comment: I didn't know time had anything to do with it.

Comment: @doubleaa, if that is indeed the case why not provide an answer saying that its not time-dependent.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18741/759

Answer (score 1):

It is an important question as there is a prohibition of bracha levatala and I also asked it.

Answer I was given is that if you originally had the intent to eat/drink over a prolonged period of time, you do not make a bracha again. For instance, if you drink something as you work/learn, the original blessing covers you for many hours as long as you are in the same place/under the same roof. This is especially the case if the/your *normal practice* is to eat/drink multiple times in the same place.

My rav says his rav would make one blessing for all the water he would drink over hours of study.

See [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/types-of-blessings/) for some more details.

PS. Noticed by "coincidence" a while after writing that it had already been answered on MiYodeya [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18741/what-brachot-do-you-say-and-when-if-you-drink-intermittently-all-day)

PPS. Coincidence, MikReH in Hebrew = Rak Me Hashem :->